# Josephus in Scheme

Tags: scheme, josephus

Where does this implementation of the Josephus problem fall short? For those who are unfamiliar with the Josephus Problem, the goal is to delete every 3rd entry from a circularly linked list until only one remains. In this example I am deleting every "mth" value.

```
(define (joseph lst)  
(let ((m (+ 1 (random (length lst)))))
(define (joseph-h i xlst mlst)
 (cond ((<= (length xlst) 1) xlst)
       ((null? (cdr mlst)) 
        (joseph-h i xlst xlst))
       ((= i m) 
        (joseph-h 1 (delete (car mlst) xlst) (cdr mlst)))
       (else 
        (joseph-h (+ i 1) xlst (cdr mlst)))))
 (joseph-h 0 lst lst)))

 (joseph (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))


 (define (delete v lst)
   (cond ((= v (car lst)) 
          (cdr lst))
         (else
          (cons (car lst) (delete v (cdr lst))))))
```

I always end up with the last number of the list as the answer. I know that this is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the algorithm too literally, by creating a list and deleting elements ("killing" people) from it. A simpler solution would be to use arithmetic operations to model the problem, here's a possible implementation, adapted from my own [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932947/201359):

```
(define (joseph n k)
  (let loop ([i   1]
             [acc 0])
    (if (> i n)
        (add1 acc)
        (loop (add1 i)
              (modulo (+ acc k) i)))))
```

For example, to see which position survives in the list `'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` after killing every third person, do this:

```
(joseph 7 3)
=> 4
```

Wikipedia provides an interesting [discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#Solution) regarding the possible solutions for this problem, my solution adapts the simple python function shown, after converting it to tail recursion.

Comment: Darn, this solution is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I give three solutions at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/flavius-josephus/2/). The most literal version deletes from a list of *n* items in steps of *m*, representing the list as a cyclic list:

```
(define (cycle xs)
  (set-cdr! (last-pair xs) xs) xs)

(define (josephus3 n m)
  (let loop ((k (- m 1)) (alive (cycle (range 0 n))) (dead '()))
    (cond ((= (car alive) (cadr alive))
            (reverse (cons (car alive) dead)))
          ((= k 1)
            (let ((dead (cons (cadr alive) dead)))
              (set-cdr! alive (cddr alive))
              (loop (- m 1) (cdr alive) dead)))
```

This does the deletions by actually removing the killed elements from the `alive` list and placing them on the `dead` list. The `range` function is from my [Standard Prelude](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/); it returns the integers from 0 to `n-1`:

```
(define (range first past . step)
  (let* ((xs '()) (f first) (p past)
         (s (cond ((pair? step) (car step))
                  ((< f p) 1) (else -1)))
         (le? (if (< 0 s) <= >=)))
    (do ((x f (+ x s))) ((le? p x) (reverse xs))
      (set! xs (cons x xs)))))
```

The original Josephus problem killed 41 men in steps of 3, leaving the 31st man as the survivor, counting from 1:

> (josephus3 41 3)
>   (2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 0 4 9 13 18 22 27 31 36
>   40 6 12 19 25 33 39 7 16 28 37 10 24 1 21 3 34 15 30)

You might also enjoy the other two versions at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/flavius-josephus/2/).

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out.